# Remove rows with top and bottom x, y distinct values

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have the following table ordered by `val`. I would like to remove all rows that share the top and bottom x and y distinct values in the `source` column.

If x is 1 and y is 2, then on this table:

| val | source |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 7 | 4 |
| 7 | 5 |
| 9 | 5 |

The result should be:

| val | source |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 |

Where 2 rows was were removed because the top row `source = 1` and 4 rows were removed because the bottom 2 distinct values in source was 4 and 5.

How could I achieve this result?

Comment: *table ordered by val.* Incorrect - this column contains duplicated values.

Comment: The example is produced by an 'order by'. How should I write it then?

Comment: *The example is produced by an 'order by'.* WHAT IS precise ordering expression? `ORDER BY val`? If so then your ordering is not deterministic which makes the whole task unsolvable.

Comment: It is indeed ordered by `val` and I'm aware the ordering is not deterministic, but I have yet to figure out what other data I can use to solve this problem

Answer (score 2):

```sql
WITH 
cte1 AS (
  SELECT val, 
         source,
         COALESCE(source <> LAG(source) OVER (ORDER BY val), 1) like_prev, 
         COALESCE(source <> LEAD(source) OVER (ORDER BY val), 1) like_next
  FROM test
),
cte2 AS (
  SELECT val,
         source,
         SUM(like_prev) OVER (ORDER BY val) sum_prev,
         SUM(like_next) OVER (ORDER BY val DESC) sum_next
  FROM cte1
)
DELETE test
FROM test
JOIN cte2 USING (source)
WHERE cte2.sum_prev <= @x
   OR cte2.sum_next <= @y;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/1bRF9BpU (the values in `val` are made unique).

Comment: Finally figured out how your query works, definitely more advanced than what I can write myself.
Unfortunately it seems your solution is incompatible with MySQL 5.7, which I am bound to as it runs on AWS. Are you able to help me with a version of the query that can run on version 5.7?

Comment: @Akina can you please say how to translate this part of your code- source <> LAG(source) OVER (ORDER BY val) in Sql Server? i try using a case but no luck. Thank you in advance!

Comment: @Florin *in Sql Server* ??? SQL Server (MS SQL) <> MySQL !!!

Comment: @Florin *how to translate this part of your code- `source <> LAG(source) OVER (ORDER BY val)`* SQL Server does not perform implicit boolean->integer convertion, so you must use `CASE WHEN source <> LAG(source) OVER (ORDER BY val) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` instead.